# ExpandableListView is not responding

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using ExpandableListView in my project. The problem that i am facing is - after I expand few groups and close them (and do this multiple times) the ExpandableListView is not responding (eating lot of CPU resource). I don't know the exact reason. Following is what I did:
(I tested this on Android 2.2 OS)

XML Layout

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/explistView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:groupIndicator="@null"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent" 
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
```

Adapter

```
ExpandableListView explistView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explistView);
explistView.setAdapter(new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(this));

// SimpleExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
```

Comment: you could use traceview and debug this kind of problem. Check here http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: You really need to post the adapter code, that is most likely where the issue is.